# Jupyter Notebook Tensorflow "object_detection_tutorial" imports error. (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.protobuf')

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter

I can't solve the error I mentioned below. Can you please help? I tried all kinds of methods. No solution I've tried has resolved this error. I watch lecture videos online. They do not encounter such errors in the video content I watch. I'm new to Tensorflow software. If there is a resource you can suggest to me, could you please specify?

These files were prepared from "Jupyter Notebook".

[Error Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZxIo.png)

**Attached Files**

```
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model
```

**Error Codes**

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-5b72732c4197> in <module>
      4 import sys
      5 import tarfile
----> 6 import tensorflow as tf
      7 import zipfile
      8 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow-2.6.0rc0-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow-2.6.0rc0-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     39 
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     41 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
     42 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow-2.6.0rc0-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in <module>
     30 import six
     31 
---> 32 from tensorflow.core.framework import function_pb2
     33 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
     34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow-2.6.0rc0-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\tensorflow\core\framework\function_pb2.py in <module>
      5 import sys
      6 _b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
----> 7 from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
      8 from google.protobuf import message as _message
      9 from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.protobuf'
```

**I have specified the "pip" files below**

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
!pip install tf_slim
!pip install crcmod
!pip install opencv-python
!pip install dm-tree
!pip install importlib-resources
!pip install promise
!pip install tensorflow-metadata
!pip install google-api-core==1.21.0
!pip install google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
!pip install uritemplate==3.0.0
!pip install avro-python3!==1.8.1
!pip install protobuf
!pip install grpcio
!pip install grpcio-tools
!pip3 install six numpy wheel
!pip3 install keras_applications==1.0.6 --no-deps
!pip3 install keras_preprocessing==1.0.5 --no-deps
!pip install bazel
!pip install ipython
!pip install google
!pip install protobuf
!pip install tensorflow as tf
!pip install tensorflow-object-detection-api==0.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions-

1. `conda install -c anaconda protobuf` #if you are running in conda environment
2. pip uninstall protobuf
   pip uninstall google
   pip install google
   pip install protobuf
3. 

```
Create an empty __init__.py in   ./site-packages/google directory in case __init__.py file is missing
```

Ref- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6341